# Very slow rendering of Quantity

Tags: curated-data, units, finance

I noticed since Mathematica v12 a very slow frontend when rendering the Units.

Easy to show:

```
Quantity[Range[1, 100], "Euros"]
```

Takes (timed with a stopwatch) approx. 17 seconds..
Is it my computer?

```
Quantity[Range[1, 100], "Euros"];
```

has immediate result.
When using `FinancialData` it's almost impossible to show the results in the Notebook.

Any thoughts appreciated

Comment: If you don't care about tooltips etc: `TextString /@ Quantity[Range[100], "Euros"]`

Comment: `Quantity[Range[1, 100], "Euros"]` takes less than 2 sec on my MacBook Pro (3 GHz Intel Core i7) with macOS 10.14.5

Comment: 8 seconds in Mma12, Windows 7Pro, i7-4770  3.4GHz 16Gb RAM, I have noticed the problem before. I agree that this is slow.

Comment: I use a Windows 10 with a i7-6820HQ@2.7GHz 16GB RAM. I find it unworkable slow... sigh..

Comment: I logged a support Call. Anyway I also note that when I minimize the Notebook and then open the window again, the notebook is black. Then after some seconds it comes back again. Since @BobHanlon MAC is "only" 2 seconds .. could it be a windows related issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I logged a call and it's a known issue. Will be fixed in a upcoming next release of Mathematica. Pinky Swear.

Update: presumably version 12.1

Just tested this again and with Mathematica 12.1 it's now taking 0.0000891091950117 seconds on the same computer.